# Shift problem of cipher with Vigenere in C

Tags: c, encryption, cs50, vigenere

I am extremely new to programming and I'm having some difficulties with Vigenere in C from the edX course CS50. I have broken the problem down into uppercase letters and lowercase letters and I am only trying to solve the uppercase letter problem right now. I am using the word 'panda' as my key and 'ILIKEYOU' as the plaintext. When I run the program, the first letter corresponds to the letter I'd expect it to be (23=X). After that, the program just seems to spit out random numbers for the remaining 7 letters. I haven't converted back to ASCII since I'm having so many problems with my code. Any ideas what is going on? Thank you all so much for the help :)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
// Print error message if the user imput is executed without any 
command-line arguments or with more than one command-line argument
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./vigenere k\n");
    return 1;
}

// Access key
string key = argv[1];

// Convert the array from a string to an int
int letter;
letter = atoi(argv[1]);

// Print error message if the user imput is one command-line argument 
and contains *any* non-alphabetical character(s)
for (int c = 0; c < strlen(key); c++)
{
    if (!isalpha (key[c]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere k\n");
        return 1;
    }
 }

// Prompt the user for a string of plaintext
string p;
p = get_string("plaintext:");

//Print ciphertext
printf("ciphertext: ");

 // Accessing each character in the plaintext
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++)
{
    // Shift letters only in the plaintext
    if (isalpha(p[i]))
    {

        // Convert plaintext and key to ASCII capital letters to 
        alphabetical index
        // Encipher capital letters in plaintext and print
        int c = 0;
        if (isupper(p[i]))
        {
           printf("%i\n", ((p[i] - 65) + (toupper(key[c]) - 65)) % 26);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Needs few modifications -

```
int index_key = 0;
int shift= 0;
int key_len = strlen(key);
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++)
{
    // Shift letters only in the plaintext
    if (isalpha(p[i]))
    {
        // Convert plaintext and key to ASCII capital letters to 
        //alphabetical index
        // Encipher capital letters in plaintext and print
        if (isupper(p[i]))
        {
           shift = ((p[i] - 'A') + (toupper(key[index_key % key_len]) - 'A')) % 26;
           index_key++;
           printf("%c", p[i] + shift);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Srivatahc thank you so much for the help! I understand everything except [index_key % key_len]...

Comment: `index_key % key_len` is just to wrap around to the start after you reach the end of the key (when the length of the key is less than the length of the message to encrypt).